# plantuml error rootcause net.sourceforge.plantuml.svek.EmptySvgException

Tags: plantuml

I started with plantuml to draw my class diagram on eclipe.

When i selected one class (java file), the entity class appears well in the plantuml window.
But, when i selected more than one (example 2 classes), the plantUML window generates errors (...plantuml error rootcause net.sourceforge.plantuml.svek.EmptySvgException...).

I installed graphviz 2.44. I generated the dot.exe under \bin.

[image]

Have you any idea the source of this problem ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [answer](https://github.com/hallvard/plantuml/issues/173#issuecomment-1729429056) to the same issue on GitHub.